# Does not work route in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following routing:

```
.when('/profile/:page/:account', {

templateUrl: function (params) {

var template = '/personal.html';
return template;
},
controller: 'EditController'
})
```

My URL link is:

```
site.com/profile#/privacy/1
```

Comment: so what is your problem statement ?

Comment: Your url should be in this format `site.com/profile#/1/1`

Comment: angular starts routing after `#` sign - so i think, your URL will be recognized when it will look like `site.com#/profile/privacy/1` (or similar)

Comment: Why is double /1/1? My first param is `privacy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used two params, but the link have only one params value, so your URL should be look like this below formate

```
site.com/profile#/1/1
```